# How can I convert an RGB image to grayscale but keep one color? - Java

Tags: java, colors, rgb, grayscale

I am trying to create an effect similar to Sin City or other movies where they remove all colors except one from an image.

I have an RGB image which I want to convert to grayscale but I want to keep one color.

This is my picture:
[Image to edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQNq3.png)

I want to keep the red color. The rest should be grayscale.

Here is my code so far:

```
package poza;
import java.io.*;

public class poza {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try {
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("poza.bmp");
            BufferedInputStream dis=new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            FileOutputStream sif=new FileOutputStream("poza1.bmp");
            BufferedOutputStream bos=new BufferedOutputStream(sif);
            byte[] sti=new byte[54];
            dis.read(sti,0,54);
            bos.write(sti);
            while(dis.available()>0)
            {
                int b,g,r;
                b=dis.read();
                g=dis.read();
                r=dis.read();
                System.out.print(b+" "+g+" "+r+"\n");
                int gri=(int)(0.114*b+0.587*g+0.299*r);
                if(r>=b && r>=g)
                {
                    bos.write(gri);
                    bos.write(gri);
                    bos.write(r);
                }
                else
                {
                    bos.write(b);
                    bos.write(g);
                    bos.write(r);
                    
                }
                
                System.out.print(b+" "+g+" "+r+"\n");

            }
            dis.close();
            bos.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of "one color"? Let's say I'd want to keep "yellow", which values would that involve?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQNq3.png do you mean which rgb code of this image do i want to keep?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69736054/how-can-i-convert-an-rgb-image-to-grayscale-but-keep-one-color-java i saw this link and here is exactly what i would like to now, but he was searching for a matlab code, not for a java one.

Comment: To turn non-red pixels into grey, your `else` part will need to write the same values for r g and b.

Comment: Can u give me the code example?

Comment: You've linked your own question as the matlab example. In any case the logic should be the same.

Comment: I don't have time to post a complete answer right now but two things: 1) your greyscale method is not a correct one, you need to linearize first and the use the correct coefficients, not .299 .587 as they are for the obsolete NTSC system. sRGB is ` r*0.2126+g*0.7152+b*0.0722 ` 2) The red tomato is not one color the tomato is a lot of colors from pink to dark red, perhaps with similar hue. For accurate hue, use CIELUV LCh (or CAM16), then constrain the hue value to the desired hue ±threshold, and make everything else greyscale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to note that every color is represented by 3 values or channels, i.e. red, green and blue. If you only keep one of those channels you'll skew the results.

Instead you need to decide whether a pixel should retain its original color or become grayscale. So assuming your code already does the conversion to grayscale correctly, it comes down to this:

```
if( keepColor ) {
  //I'll keep the order of the components that your example uses, make sure this is correct
  bos.write(b);
  bos.write(g);
  bos.write(r);
} else {
   bos.write(gri); //b
   bos.write(gri); //g
   bos.write(gri); //r
}
```

So what is left is how `keepColor` is defined and that depends on your requirements. A simple option might be to pick a color and check if the pixel is within a certain threshold of that color, e.g. like this:

```
/**
  * value - the value to check
  * base - the base value to check against, i.e. the center of the range, expressed in range [0, 255]
  * difference - the allowable difference in percent, expressed in range [0.0, 1.0]
  */ 
boolean withinThreshold(int value, int base, double difference) {
   return value>= base * (1-difference) //check lower bound
     && value <= base * (1+difference); //check upper bound
}
```

Then pick a value and a difference, e.g. like this:

```
boolean keepColor = withinThreshold(r, 228, 0.6) //40%-160% of 228 
                  && withinThreshold(g, 95, 0.6) //40%-160% of 95
                  && withinThreshold(b, 78, 0.6); //40%-160% of 78
```

Of course there are many other possibilities you can play around with, i.e. different thresholds, different colors, based on brightness (grayscale value in a certain range) etc.

Comment: As it happens the OP's conversion to greyscale is not correct as he doe snto linearize and is using the wrong coefficients. Your point is correct about using a threshold or range, though it's useful to note that might not result in a perceptually useful result, as hue is probably what the OP is trying to preserve, which would require a perceptually uniform color model like LUV or LAB. But if you wanted something in a narrow range and hue shift was not a concern your answer is most direct...